# Foreach for arrays inside of an array in controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, codeigniter-3

I have array of array and I did a `print_r` of it and it returned this...

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [cust_id] => xl 
            [project_id] => central 
            [tot_ticket] => 1 
            [person] => jamesbay@example.com ) 
        [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [cust_id] => tsel 
            [project_id] => jabo1 
            [tot_ticket] => 1 
            [person] => jamesbay@example.com ) 
        [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [cust_id] => isat 
            [project_id] => jabo2 
            [tot_ticket] => 1 
            [person] => jamesbay@example.com ) ) )
```

I write this in my controller right now:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($customerField); $i++) {
                for ($j=0; $j<count($activityField); $j++) { 
                    for ($k=0; $k<count($userIdField); $k++) { 
                        array_push($data, $this->queries_trend->fetch_ajax($customerField[$i], $activityField[$j], $userIdField[$k]));
                            foreach ($data as $value) {
                                $test .= '
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>' . $value[$i][$j]['cust_id']->cust_id . '</td>
                                                <td>' . $value[$i][$j]['project_id'] ->project_id. '</td>
                                                <td>' . $value[$i][$j]['tot_ticket']->tot_ticket . '</td>
                                                <td>' . $value[$i][$j]['person']->person . '</td>
                                            </tr>';    
                            }
                    }

                }
            }
```

I have problem to get the value of each array, anyone here can help me to find the solution?

Comment: you just need a two foreach loop

Comment: okay, i'll try sir

Comment: i've make for two foreach loop, the errors are "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the data from an object using `['cust_id']->cust_id`,
but you have an array, so you could use just `['cust_id']` instead.

Try using for example a foreach:

```
$test = "";
foreach ($arrays as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $test .= "<tr>";
        $test .= "<td>" . $value["cust_id"] . "</td>";
        $test .= "<td>" . $value["project_id"] . "</td>";
        $test .= "<td>" . $value["tot_ticket"] . "</td>";
        $test .= "<td>" . $value["person"] . "</td>";
        $test .= "</tr>";
    }
}

echo $test;
```